# file not being added by require once

Tags: php

I am getting no error but `INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php'` is not including the file...the path is right but still nothing is happening...could anyone please explain how to solve this issue.

```
require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.client.php');

echo INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php';
if( file(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php'))
echo "here";


  require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php');
  echo "file included";
```

here gets printed but file included is not printed
Thanks

Comment: have you enabled error reporting?

Comment: yes error reporting is enabled

Comment: What is the output? And what do you expect to happen and what does happen? Does 'here' get printed?

Comment: Try `if( file(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php') && is_readable(INCLUDE_DIR.'class.ticket.php'))` and also make sure that there's no PHP errors in your `class.ticket.php` file.

Comment: Have you already included it?require_once will only include it if it has not already been included.

Comment: @gnur `here` does get printed but `file included` is not printed...anyhthing in the included file is also not printed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check whether a file exists, use [file_exists()](http://php.net/file_exists) function, not [file()](http://php.net/file) function. What you're doing is something absolutely different, you're reading the specified file into an array (that you haven't specified). From there on, you can continue debugging your code.

Answer (score 3):

Is it really not included ?

Try run:

```
var_dump( get_included_files());
```

( http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php )

ps: as a side note, don't use if (file($var)), use if (file_exists($var))